# Flex Actionscript PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, actionscript, flex4.5, amfphp

The more I read the more it confuses me...

So inside action script I write down the functions of the flex mobile project, and inside the php files I write down the functions that I use to contact the database with?

Are there any sample applications that uses both actionscript and PHP . Now I am also getting confused about amfphp.   Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any amfphp yet, it is for some advanced cases.

To save smth to database you already have a correct picture: your database commands (SQL commands using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) should be in the .php files.

And from your mobile flex app you call those .php files using either [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html), URLStream (slightly more advanced) or [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html).

Here a View from my app, it loads a weekly top of players from PostgreSQL in JSON format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        viewActivate="startLoading(event)"
        viewDeactivate="cancelLoading(event)"
        title="Weekly top">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="BACK"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/low-res/back.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/mid-res/back.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/high-res/back.png')"/>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="LOAD"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/low-res/load-top.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/mid-res/load-top.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/high-res/load-top.png')"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button icon="{BACK}" label.landscape="Back" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <s:actionContent>
        <s:BusyIndicator symbolColor="0xFFFFFF" />
    </s:actionContent>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.brokenfunction.json.decodeJson;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

            private const TOP:String = 'http://XXXX.com/top-json.php';

            private var _urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            private function startLoading(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void {
                _urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
                _urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(TOP));
            }

            private function cancelLoading(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void {
                _urlLoader.close();
            }

            private function handleComplete(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                try {
                    var obj:Object = decodeJson(loader.data, true);
                    navigator.pushView(Top, obj.aaData);
                } catch (e:Error) {
                    trace('Invalid JSON: ' + loader.data);
                    navigator.popView();
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    

    <s:BitmapImage source="{LOAD}" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" scaleMode="letterbox" />
</s:View>
```